# Match names in column A and B, then count occurrences in C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have a scoring spreadsheet which tracks games played and the winner of each match. We have the following columns

- column A (name1)
- column B (vs)
- column C (name2)
- column D (winner name)

I have used

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="name1")*(C:C="name2")+(A:A="name2")*(C:C="name1"))
```

to count how many games this particular pairing have played, simply because as the games are entered by different people names are in either column.

Now I need to find a way to count the amount wins from the games these two have played, obviously the formula above is redundant for this.

So in effect, match from column A and C `name1` and `name2` and count how many `name1` exists in column D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be sufficient to count how many times Name1 exists in column D with Name2 in A or C so try either

`=COUNTIFS(D:D,"Name1",A:A,"Name2")+COUNTIFS(D:D,"Name1",C:C,"Name2")`

or you can use SUMPRODUCT like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((D:D="Name1")*((A:A="Name2")+(C:C="Name2")))`

The first one is longer but more efficient

Comment: Brilliant, and such a quick reply. The countifs solution works perfectly.Many thanks to you Barry! 

*Can't upvote due to reputation ;\